# Local version of my WordPress site not loading any stylesheets

Tags: php, css, wordpress, xampp

I have a development version (using XAMPP) of my WordPress site and for some reason, I cannot load stylesheets or images.

If I look at the source code through the browser, I can see that the URL is correct. For example, I have this code for an image:

```html
<img src="http://MyWebsite.loc/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/FB-images.png" class="img-responsive">
```

I have copied and pasted the link ("http://MyWebsite.loc/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/FB-images.png") into a browser and I can see the image, so it's clearly the correct URL. I have done the same thing with my stylesheets with the same results.

When looking at the "Sources" tab of Chrome developer tools, I see this error:
"failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 404"

I have been researching this for days and none of the solutions I have found on here have worked for me.

Thanks

Comment: Normal error is running in a sub folder of the DirectoryRoot which changes the real url

Comment: Another normal error is not changing the database to match the new url of the development site

Comment: There isn't anything wrong the URL. I have copied the exact URL of the source code and my browser shows the stylesheet correctly. 

Are you referring to the "site_url" in the wp_options table?  If so, I have checked that and it is correct.

Comment: Are any styles coming through?  Or are you missing assets like images?

Comment: No styles coming through. And now that you mention it, images are not working either. It seems to be a similar issue. The src URL is correct though.

Comment: After many hours of frustration, I have finally figured it out. Somehow  this line of code was added into the child theme's header: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">

It appeasrs this forces https which must have then interfered with my local links.